# Python/pandas equivalent to R's rm()

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas

```
df1 = pandas.read_csv('')
df2 = df1[['a', 'b']]
```

Now I want to remove df1 from memory. I could just make not make df2, and just make `df1 = df1[[]]`, but later I import further datasets and append them together, so no matter what I'll need to remove those extra datasets from memory.

In R, I would use `rm(df1)` and it would be removed from memory.

Thanks. I would really assume this is a duplicate, but nothing popped up in my search.

Comment: you can call `del df1` but the memory may not be released immediately, you could use `gc.collect` after `import gc` but again this may not release the memory. Why not just overwrite the df? so `df1 = df1[['a','b']]`?

Comment: As I said, I could just overwrite `df1`. But later I'm doing something like `df_combine = df1.append(df3)`. So at this point I wont need df1 or df3 again. So my question will still stand as I have limited memory.

Comment: Well you can call `del df1` as I've suggested but the garbage collector may not release the memory back to the OS but if you're planning on allocating further resources it may reuse this allocated memory, this is probably your best bet or add `import gc` to the top of your code, and call `gc.collect()` after calling `del`

Comment: I'll try that, thanks.